# How to call the PHP function with arguments in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am getting the values from HTML form through JavaScript and I am trying to call the PHP functions which takes arguments through AJAX. But I am not able to get it done. How can I do this?

PHP code:

```
<?php
function updateJbdesc($jobdesc,$loginid) 
{
    // some code
}

?>
```

Ajax Code:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'allfunctions.php',
         data: {action: 'updateJbdesc'},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      alert(output);
                  }
});
```

How can I pass arguments to PHP function through AJAX?

Comment: where you are calling the function `updateJbdesc()`??? `putting it as action doesnt call it automatically..`

Comment: You can't call a php function through ajax directly.

Comment: i think u are using wordpress Ajax

Comment: You don't really pass arguments. You pass data via POST(in your case). Simply retrieve the POST value in the function you're calling via the AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some code to get the $_POST values and use these to call the function.

```
$val0 = $_POST[ 'val0' ];
$val1 = $_POST[ 'val1' ];
$functionId = $_POST[  'functionid' ];

$result = -1;
if( $functionId == 0 ) $result = somefunction( $val0, $val1 );
else $result = someotherfunction( $val0, $val1 );

# echo this to return result to ajax
echo $result;
```

You can pass a value via ajax to tell PHP which function you want:

```
$.ajax({ url: "myurl.php",
    data: { val0: "val0", val1: "val1", functionid: "identifier" }
}).done( function( result ) { alert( result ); });
```